# How to assign new value into combo box list?

Tags: c#, combobox

I am working with windows CE and my interface as well as its content are generated dynamically based on the selected database.

The combo box fetches values from database `(description table)` and saves the selected value `(value table)` into different table. There is no problem during insertion. The combo box works just fine.

However, when I try to perform retrieval of inserted data, the combo box can't display the inserted values. Is there any function I can use to resolve this issue?

```
selectedDescription = dr["value"].ToString().Split(',').ToList<string>(); 

if (dr["type"].ToString() == "multiple") {

        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.DataSource = selectedDescription;
        combo.Width = 60;
        combo.Height = 27;
        combo.Location = new Point(currentX, currentY);
        combo.Tag = Id;
```

//If the getVal is not null (means there is value selected/inserted for this particular combo), then the combo.DataSource should be the inserted value.

However, when I assign `combo.Datasource = ds["val"].ToString();`, I cannot open this module on the device. And then I tried `combo.SelectedValue`, but the combo box displays `selectedDescription` instead.

```
if (getVal != null) {

    foreach (DataRow ds in getVal.Tables[0].Rows) {

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ds["descId"].ToString()) == combo.Tag)
        {

            combo.SelectedValue = ds["val"].ToString();

        }
```

Comment: It seems you have to control page postback by writing this : if (Page.IsPostBack) { return; } Because after postback, the ComboBox's blank data will be seen.

Comment: is it windows form or webform related question ?

Comment: could you demonstrate/modify my codes @hqtunes.com?

Comment: this is windows form related @Mou

Comment: briefly tell me problem again....so i may try!

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot to write this : You should write my code to Page Load method. Okey I'm checking.

Comment: Well, @Mou my programs are dynamic based program and that includes interface.  The combo box list is based on the data in the database. There is no problem upon retrieving these data.  New id is generated every successful insertion.  I need to retrieve the selected value for update function.  However, I can't display the selected value using combo.selectedValue.

Comment: u can only show selected value if it is already there in combo. suppose combo is showing 1,2,3....10 if i need to select 11 as value for combo then combo will not be able to show 11 as selected value.

Comment: What should I do then? If you notice the `selectedDescription` is separated by `,`.  The selected value is stored in different table. How do i assign the inserted value and the rest of the list into combo box? Can you help me @Mou?

Comment: find the value which u try to add in combo first. if not found then add it first and then select it. if found then select it like this way combo.SelectedValue = ds["val"].ToString();

Comment: @Mou could you demonstrate/modify my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have develop a sample for you to handle your situation

here i first add some data to combobox

```
   // first databind combobox
    string cboData="1,2,3,4,5";
    comboBox1.DataSource = cboData.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

now try to add some value after data bind.
so first i will search data if found then set it but if not found then add it to data source and set the data.

```
    int i = comboBox1.FindStringExact("6");
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "6";
    }
    else
    {
        List<string> str1 = (List<string>)comboBox1.DataSource;
        str1.Add("6");
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        comboBox1.DataSource = str1;
        comboBox1.Text = "6";
    }
```

if still code is not clear then ask me.

Comment: besides FindStringExact function, what other function that I can use?

Comment: what is the problem u r facing to use function "FindStringExact " ?

Comment: better to search MSDN for combobox and there u can see all search related function there.

Comment: There is no "FindStringExact" function for my combo box. ok, Thank you!!

Comment: which dotnet version u r using? i used dotnet 4.0

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am using dotnet 3.5

Comment: if you use 3.5 then u should get this function FindStringExact(). i gave u the MSDN link then see and let me know. thanks

Comment: I can't use that function. I use this function instead -> IndexOf.